# DrawArc is Coming up Short

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am having a small issue with using `Graphics.DrawArc` method. When used it's coming up short than what the actual size is. I am basing this control off another post found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928523/visual-basic-circular-progress-bar)

I am trying to make this into a `UserControl` with some properties and expand on it. The issue is when I set the percentage per say 50% it comes up short...

This is what the `UserControl` looks like at 50%... It's should be centered (blue) at the bottom of circle. I have tried adjusting everything I could, but I am at lost right now.

[image]

Here is my current code...

```
Color _ProgressCompletedColor = SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
    Color _ProgressNotCompleted = Color.LightGray;
    Int32 _ProgressThickness = 2;
    Single _ProgressCompleted = 25;

    public AttuneProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Single PercentageCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProgressCompleted;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProgressCompleted = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Int32 ProgressBarThickness
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProgressThickness;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProgressThickness = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color ProgressNotCompletedColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProgressNotCompleted;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProgressNotCompleted = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color ProgressCompletedColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ProgressCompletedColor;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ProgressCompletedColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call the OnPaint method of the base class.
        base.OnPaint(e);

        DrawProgress(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(new Point(1,1), new Size(this.ClientSize.Width - 3, this.ClientSize.Height - 3)), PercentageCompleted);
    }

    private void DrawProgress(Graphics g, Rectangle rec, Single percentage)
    {  
        Single progressAngle = (360 / 100 * percentage);
        Single remainderAngle = 360 - progressAngle;

        try
        {
            using (Pen progressPen = new Pen(ProgressCompletedColor, ProgressBarThickness), remainderPen = new Pen(ProgressNotCompletedColor, ProgressBarThickness))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.DrawArc(progressPen, rec, -90, progressAngle);
                g.DrawArc(remainderPen, rec, progressAngle - 90, remainderAngle);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the angle with integers. When you do this:

```
angle = 360 / 100 * percentage;
```

it means

```
angle = 3 * percentage;
```

this of course leads to errors. There is a simple fix if you want to keep using ints:

```
angle = 360 * percentage / 100;
```

This way it doesn't get rounded down before multiplication. Or you can just use floats all the way:

```
angle = 360f / 100f * percentage;
```

Comment: better to use floats for the constant numbers.

Comment: @MarkusEgle In this case maybe, but when using only ints and the result also should be int changing the order is the best way. Of course excluding overflows, which have to be made sure there are none.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you are 100% correct, dang types got me again! This works great, it was bothering me for about an hour today and just couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. Thank's Again!