# How to Mix Form Fields and Graphics?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, graphics, progress-bar

I am trying to use the circular progress bar solution that was provided at

[Visual basic circular progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928523/visual-basic-circular-progress-bar)

However I am getting a lot of error messages when I try to incorporate it within a Windows Form that has textbox entries (have to do with System.EventArgs versus PaintEventArgs and MyBase.Load versus Me.Paint).

I tried "mixing" both handles like this:

Private Sub LoginForm1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs, g as PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, Me.Paint

but of course that bombed out. Can someone please advise what are my alternatives here?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you think combining those event handlers was a good idea? You can't just arbitrarily decide what arguments an existing event will pass to its handlers. If you want to handle the `Load` event of a form then do that. If you want to handle the `Paint` event of a form then do that. Two different events; two different event handlers. Put the code to execute at load in one and the code to do the drawing in the other. Simple.

Comment: I just looked at the other question. All you need to do is copy and paste the code provided. If anything doesn't work it's because you broke it so just don't break it and there's no question to ask.

Comment: ok-- referring to the code provided how do I DrawProgress from my form? DrawProgress requires an e.Graphics entry which cannot be done through my form since it does not handle PaintEventArgs, just EventArgs.

Comment: As you subscribed to the Load event, also subscribe to the Paint event, as shown in that code. It's not really clear what problem you might have with that.

Comment: This is what I want to do--- depending on the entry for the texto variable, I want to DrawProgress----- it gives me an error... Private Sub LoginForm1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Show()
        If texto <> "" Then
            DrawProgress(e.Graphics, New Rectangle(260, 55, 60, 60), 0)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: `If texto <> "" Then DrawProgress(e.Graphics, New Rectangle(260, 55, 60, 60), 0) End If` goes to the `Paint` event handler, not the `Load` handler. What is `Me.Show()` doing in the `Load` handler? Remove that.

Comment: Ok, let me try another approach here--- I want to have my main form (using regular textboxes, etc. that need to have EventArgs) call the DrawProgress sub for specific milestones (percentages) such that the progress bar arrives eventually to 100%. How do I call it from my main form?

Comment: A TextBox doesn't have `EventArgs`, event handlers may. When *something* changes in a TextBox, convert the text to a Single or Integer value and set a Field that is used in one of the `DrawProgress()` calls, then `Invalidate()` the Form. `Invalidate()` will raise the Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking something very easy and making it hard. ALL drawing gets done in the `Paint` event handler or a method called from the `Paint` event handler. That's it, that's all when it comes to drawing. You already know how to do that because you already have the code to do it from another question. Use that code.

If the code that does the drawing needs to get data from elsewhere to know what to draw then do that. There's nothing magical about a method using the value of one or more fields to do its work. The data in that field(s) can be put there by any other method, e.g. the `Load` event handler of the form, the `TextChanged` event handler of a `TextBox` or the `Click` event handler of `Button`.

Here's a simple example that will draw whatever is in a `TextBox` as the user types:

```vb
Private textToDraw As String

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Text
    textToDraw = TextBox1.Text

    'Force a Paint event to be raised.
    Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textToDraw, Font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty)
End Sub
```

Put the data where it can be accessed, raise a `Paint` event, do the drawing. Simple!

The main point to note there is that calling `Invalidate` with no arguments will cause the entire control it's called on (the form, in this case) to be repainted and that should be avoided if possible. You should calculate and specify the smallest area possible that has or could have changed and pass that when calling `Invalidate`. That way, parts of the control that definitely haven't changed will not be repainted, speeding up the process. You draw everything every time but the actual repainting of pixels on the screen is the slow part of the operation and so should be minimised. You might read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684) for more information.